# Disable auto-pair when using multiple cursors in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, multiple-cursor

I am using the vim plugins vim-multiple-cursors and auto-pairs. If I am editing a block of text for example:

```
one
two
three
four
```

If I highlight the block with the command

```
vip <ctrl-n> I "
```

this will create two parenthesis in the front because auto-pairs is active.

```
""one
""two
""three
""four
```

Is there a way to have auto-pairs turn off automatically when you are using vim-multiple cursors?

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

""""""""" PLUGIN LIST STARTS HERE """"""""""""""""""""
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
""""""""" PLUGIN LIST END HERE """"""""""""""""""""
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " requiredntax on

syntax on
set tabstop=4
set number
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set mouse=a
set backspace=indent,eol,start

let &t_SI.="\e[5 q"
let &t_SR.="\e[4 q"
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q"

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '▸'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '▾'
map <F5> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'clang++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autopairs has a function called `AutoPairsToggle()` which you need to call before entering and after leaving multiple cursors mode.

vim-multiple-cursors [provides you](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors#interactions-with-other-plugins) with a way to resolve plugin interactions: define a pre and post hook:

```vimscript
function! Multiple_cursors_before()
  call AutoPairsToggle()
endfun

function! Multiple_cursors_after()
  call AutoPairsToggle()
endfun
```

Put these in your `.vimrc` and the problem should no longer occur.

Answer (score 2):

On its help system auto-pairs says:

```
    <M-p>: Toggle Autopairs (g:AutoPairsShortcutToggle)
```

Hence, before typing something press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: in macbook what key are M ?

Comment: In my "Acer" or any other PC it stands for "Alt" key.

Comment: @JuniorUsca while using iTerm2 go to Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys  --- there change the left option key from Normal to Esc+ or checkout this link https://developpaper.com/summary-of-vim-auto-pairs/

Comment: @JuniorUsca M is option